# alternative to die() in jquery 1.9

Tags: jquery

The `.die()` method has been removed from jQuery 1.9. Any idea of how to achieve the same thing? I'm trying to kill a click handlers on page load on some links.

Thanks

Comment: I doubt you looked for that yourself. Type jquery and die in google, find the API for .die() in the first link, and scroll down to the warning saying you should use .off() from now on.

Comment: jQuery usually keeps their [API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/) up to date with deprecation alternatives. Always check there first.

Answer (score 6):

Use `off()` - Documentation for `off()`: http://api.jquery.com/off/

Answer (score 2):

The [jQuery Core 1.9 Upgrade Guide](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/) is a fantastic resource with instructions for how to handle deprecated/removed functions and other breaking changes in 1.9.

Quote from there:

> The .die() method has been deprecated since jQuery 1.7 and has been removed in 1.9. We recommend upgrading code to use the .off() method instead. To exactly match $("a.foo").die("click"), for example, you can write $(document).off("click", "a.foo"). For more information, see the .off() documentation. In the meantime, the jQuery Migrate plugin can be used to restore the .die() functionality.

Note that while you *should* replace `die()` with `off()`, you can also use the [Migrate plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate) if you need a quick fix that will make your existing `die()` calls work with the 1.9 core.

Comment: The `.live()` -> `.on()` switch is probably relevant to mention here as well.

Answer (score 1):

As of jQuery 1.7, use of [`.die()`](http://api.jquery.com/die/) (and its complementary method, `.live()`) is not recommended. Instead, use `.off()` to remove event handlers bound with `.on()`.